# All DKMS-managed modules fail with `Exec format error`

Tags: 18.04, kernel, dkms

All the DKMS-managed kernel modules started to fail during loading on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I noticed it with `acpi_call` so let me use that to demonstrate:

```
# uname -r
4.15.0-99-generic

# modinfo acpi_call.ko 
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/updates/dkms/acpi_call.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     72B6FB9451F0D2139482F11
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           acpi_call
vermagic:       4.15.0-99-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

# modprobe acpi_call
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'acpi_call': Exec format error
```

I have tried reinstalling it with DKMS, to no avail:

```
# dkms status acpi-call
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 4.15.0-99-generic, x86_64: installed

# dkms remove acpi-call/1.1.0 --all

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  acpi-call
Version: 1.1.0
Kernel:  4.15.0-99-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

acpi_call.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.1.0
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.

# dkms install acpi-call/1.1.0

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/source ->
                 /usr/src/acpi-call-1.1.0

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-99-generic -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build...
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/4.15.0-99-generic/x86_64/module/acpi_call.ko
Nothing to do.
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

acpi_call.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.

# modprobe acpi_call
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'acpi_call': Exec format error
```

Other modules in `/lib/modules/4.15.0-99-generic/updates/dkms` exhibit the exact same problem.

I have also tried `modprobe -f`, leading to a different error message:

```
# modprobe -f acpi_call
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'acpi_call': Required key not available
```

This led me down the [MOK rabbit hole](https://askubuntu.com/a/769840/10154) but even after enrolling a new MOK and `sign-file`-ing the `.ko` files, I am still getting the `Required key not available` error. If I disable validation, then `modprobe -f` still fails with `Exec format error`.

Also, I have noticed this line in `dmesg`:

```
[  617.320431] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 0000000057734886, val ffffffffc0d56a43
```

What is going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Well, something is broken in your system. I can't guess.

Comment: Ah ha! It seems that the problem is that it is built with GCC 9. If I build with GCC 7, it seems to work.

Comment: That's a good catch!

Comment: Default gcc in `bionic` is 7. So you changed the default and got this problem. Please write an answer, this may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the default GCC on my system got changed to GCC-9 (due to a botched `freehdl` upgrade, but whatever). This resulted in a different (and apparently, not ABI-compatible?) GCC version used for building modules with DKMS compared to the GCC version used to build the Ubuntu kernel.

After downgrading back to GCC-7 (and rebuilding all DKMS modules), everything now works as before, including Secure Boot support.